# Jenkins Pipeline with Azure Web App Deployment

Tags: git, azure, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to publish our webapp to Azure using a Jenkins pipeline and the [Azure Webapp Deployment plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Azure+App+Service+Plugin).
I cannot get it to work.
Weird thing is that I don't even get a decent error message.
My Jenkinsfile contains following

```
stage("Publish to Azure") {
    steps {
        azureWebAppPublish ([
            appName: "xxx", 
            azureCredentialsId: "xxx", 
            publishType: "file", 
            resourceGroup: "xxx", 
            sourceDirectory: "docs/export"
        ])
    }
}
```

> Starting Azure Web App Deployment
>
> Cloning repository xxx.git
>
> C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe init D:\Jenkins\workspace\xxx # timeout=10
>
> Fetching upstream changes from xxx
>
> C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe --version # timeout=10
>
> using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials
>
> C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe fetch --tags --progress xxx.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
>
> C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe config remote.origin.url xxx.git # timeout=10
>
> C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe config --add remote.origin.fetch +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* # timeout=10
>
> Seen branch in repository origin/master
>
> Seen 1 remote branch
>
> C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
>
> C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe checkout -f master

And then the pipeline fails, without a clear error ...
Any ideas?

EDIT:
When I open the job itself it shows the following:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at hudson.FilePath.isAbsolute(FilePath.java:304)
    at hudson.FilePath.glob(FilePath.java:1807)
    at hudson.FilePath.access$1900(FilePath.java:208)
    at hudson.FilePath$31.invoke(FilePath.java:1788)
    at hudson.FilePath$31.invoke(FilePath.java:1785)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1020)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:998)
    at hudson.FilePath.list(FilePath.java:1785)
    at hudson.FilePath.list(FilePath.java:1769)
    at hudson.FilePath.list(FilePath.java:1754)
    at com.microsoft.jenkins.appservice.commands.GitDeployCommand.copyAndAddFiles(GitDeployCommand.java:267)
    at com.microsoft.jenkins.appservice.commands.GitDeployCommand.execute(GitDeployCommand.java:100)
    at com.microsoft.jenkins.appservice.commands.GitDeployCommand.execute(GitDeployCommand.java:53)
    at com.microsoft.jenkins.azurecommons.command.CommandService.runCommand(CommandService.java:88)
    at com.microsoft.jenkins.azurecommons.command.CommandService.execute(CommandService.java:96)
    at com.microsoft.jenkins.azurecommons.command.CommandService.executeCommands(CommandService.java:75)
    at com.microsoft.jenkins.azurecommons.command.BaseCommandContext.executeCommands(BaseCommandContext.java:77)
    at com.microsoft.jenkins.appservice.WebAppDeploymentRecorder.perform(WebAppDeploymentRecorder.java:203)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.CoreStep$Execution.run(CoreStep.java:80)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.CoreStep$Execution.run(CoreStep.java:67)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution$1$1.call(SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:49)
    at hudson.security.ACL.impersonate(ACL.java:290)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution$1.run(SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:46)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Thanks in advance!
Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem.
filePath is a mandatory field.
Fixed using:

```
        stage("Publish to Azure") {
            steps {
                azureWebAppPublish appName: "xxx",
                    azureCredentialsId: "xxx",
                    publishType: "file",
                    filePath: "**/*.*",
                    resourceGroup: "xxx",
                    sourceDirectory: "xxx"
            }
        }
```

The exception has been fixed as you can see [here](https://github.com/jenkinsci/azure-app-service-plugin/issues/28#event-1650529035)